# XPath expression to get values between dates

Tags: xpath

I have xml stored in a xmltype table in a (Oracle Database) if the database matters

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>                                                           
<myDate xmlns="http://www.example.com/schema" dateTimeProc="20100824T102806" Num="666" timId="4" procId="1" proces="501">                                                          
</myDate>  

<?xml version="1.0"?>                                                           
<myDate xmlns="http://www.example.com/schema" dateTimeProc="20101110T102806" Num="666" timId="4" procId="1" proces="501">                                                          
</myDate>
```

I would like to know whats the xpath expression to get all xml's that are between certain dates something like

```
select * from XMLTable
where existsNode(object_value,'myDate[@dateTimeProc]') 
between sysdate-120 and sysdate-90
```

Answer (score 0):

I was interested so I started looking around.  Apparently according to http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20030627d.asp the AND directive is allowable in an xpath query.

I know that you can use > and < in the queries (according to http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp)

So I would try:

```
 //myDate[@dateTimeProc < X and @dateTimeProc > Y]
```

(where X and Y are a unix timecode that you get out of whatever code/language you're using)